# How to handle this exception in a cleaner way?

Tags: c#, foreach, nullreferenceexception

I've been trying to enumerate through a properties of a class and getting their values in a List of strings.
But i faced a problem where i get a NullReferenceException when the value is null from the properties

I Managed to Fix that by that solution, but still i don't see that as a clean code.

I Wonder if this can be implemented in a cleaner and more professional way.

```
    private int CalculateScore()
    {
        var score = 0;
        var answers = new List<string>();
        foreach (var prop in typeof(TypesSheet).GetProperties())
        {
            // WHEN STRING IS MISSING IT BREAKS
            try
            {
                var answer = prop.GetValue(_typesSheet).ToString();
                answers.Add(answer);
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }


        }

        if (_gameMode == GameMode.SinglePlayer)
        {
            foreach (var answer in answers)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer))
                    continue;

                score = score + 10;
            }

            return score;
        }
  }
```

Comment: A try catch is a terrible idea. You end up swallowing Fatal Exceptions. And swallowing those is a deadly sin of exception handling: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ |  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET This exception is very much a boneheaded one. The obvious solution would be to check for null before you use it. Aside from the simple code `if (x != null)`, there is a bunch of shorthands like the null-coalesce operator and null-conditional operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
// WHEN STRING IS MISSING IT BREAKS
try
{
    var answer = prop.GetValue(_typesSheet).ToString();
    answers.Add(answer);
}
catch
{
    continue;
}
```

With:

```
var value = prop.GetValue(_typesSheet);
if (null != value)
{
    answers.Add(value.toString());
}
```

Comment: The program crashes before it reaches the if condition

Comment: oh, it was about the ToString(); function, you can't do it to a null reference my bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (prop.GetValue(_typesheets) != null) {
    answers.Add(prop.GetValue(_typesheets));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused `prop.GetValue(_typesSheet)` might be `null`. when you use `ToString` method will get

> nullreferenceexception

You can try to use `linq` instead of the foreach.

```
var answers =
    typeof(TypesSheet).GetProperties()
    .Select(x => x.GetValue(_typesSheet))
    .Where(x=> x!= null)
    .Select(x=> x.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Safe Navigation Operator** (available in C# 6)

```
var answer = prop.GetValue(_typesSheet)?.ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer)) answers.Add(answer);
```

**Linq version**

```
var answers = typeof(TypesSheet)
                .GetProperties()
                .Select(prop => prop.GetValue(_typesSheet)?.ToString())
                .Where(answer => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer))
                .ToList();
```